# My Jquery base Drop Down Menu does not work in IE9

Tags: jquery

I have website which is used Jquery based drop down menu. This menu is work fine with all browser except the IE 9.

The link of site is http://logicnetworks.com.au/;

if you open this URL in IE7, IE8, you will see the menu in top section and that menu used the drop down to popup the sub menu.it work fine here but when you open this in IE 9, its drop down menu does not work.

Can anyone please help me to get me out of this issue ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your menu script isn't writted with jQuery, it's pure Javascript. Maybe see what is returned by TransMenu.isSupported(). Maybe remove that condtion (maybe script will work, just isSuportted method don't recognize IE9 as supporting)

Comment: Thanks you killer_PL,, I have gone through your solution but can not get success. The Same Jquery plugin i used with other site. the URl is (hhtp://demoserver.com.au/vitalline) and it work fine with IE 9